# flutter add option value to list with mandatory value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some questions that I will present to the program
Each question has two answers, either (yes) + or (no).
If I press yes, nothing happens
But if he presses (No), a box appears to add comments, and adding comments is optional, either answering yes or no is mandatory.
I store yes or no answers in list
But I do not know how to add comments with it according to each question
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can create another optional variable for comment on model class? Can you include what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh for list of yes or no void AddAnswer() async{

  Answers.add({
   'question' : Question,
   'answer' : Answer, //yes or no
  });

 }

Comment: you can include another variable as comment on `Answers` class. on `no` press show a TextField and add comment

Answer (score 1):

I'd indeed not only store yes/no, but also store the comments in the same objects. Say you now have

```dart
List<bool> answers = []; // filled with true, false as you answer
```

You could make a container class

```dart
class QuestionAnswer {
final String question;
final bool answer;
final String? comment;

QuestionAnswer({required this.question, required this.answer, this.comment});
}
```

And make a `List<QuestionAnswer>` instead, which you supply with a question, an answer and optionally also a comment